# Ruby on Rails - Add limit, order and sum on File.open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

In my application I have a `.txt` file that I `open/read` on users profile view. That `.txt` file contains some numbers.

This is what i have so far:

```
f = File.open("public/users/14/user.txt", "r")
- f.each_line do |d|
     %p= d
```

I can `put` out all the numbers that is on that file. Is it any way to add `limit` & `order (start from bottom to top)`.

I tried:

```
f.limit(4).order('DESC').each_line do |d|
```

and

```
File.open("public/users/14/user.txt", "r").limit(5)
```

When I try these I get error: `undefined method limit` or `undefined method order`.

Is it also possible to `sum` all the numbers on that file?

Comment: The error comes as there are no such methods for a file object. Those methods are defined for an ActiveRecord object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@lines = IO.readlines('public/users/14/user.txt').sort.reverse.first(4)
```

- [`IO.readlines`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-c-readlines) reads all lines into an array
- [`Array#sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-sort) sorts the array (ascending)
- [`Array#reverse`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-reverse) reverses the array (makes it descending)
- [`Array#first`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-first) returns the first *n* elements

You should put the above in your controller and use it in your view:

```
- @lines.each do |line|
  %p= line
```

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, works like a charm :) But how I am able to make `sum` for all numbers inside that file?

Comment: `@lines` is an array of strings. So first of all, you have to convert the strings to numbers (`Integer`, `Float`, or `BigDecimal` depending on your use-case), for example by calling [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-to_i). Once the elements are numbers, you can sum them using [`Enumerable#sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum), i.e. `@lines.sum`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Stefan. I tried `hb_pb.to_i` & `hb_pb.to_f` and got this error: `undefined method to_f for ["0.8\n", "0.8\n", "0.8\n", "0.4\n"]:Array`. What do I do wrong here?

Comment: You have to call `to_i` / `to_f` on the array's elements, not the array itself. Try `hp_bp.map!(&:to_f)`

Comment: Thanks a bunch @stefan

Answer (score 0):

Those are ActiveRecord methods provided by rails. I suggest you to read `IO` documentation from ruby. [Here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-read) is the documentation.

syntax is like `read(name, [length [, offset]] ) → string`

and use is like `IO.read("testfile", 20, 10)`

here 20 is length in byte and 10 is offset .

Comment: thanks @sajan. That works but not as I want. What it does is to take 20 characters from that file and it doesnt `limit` lines, it limit characters

Comment: Ok, then I guess you may have to depend on own custom conditions like suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use range for that situation. In this example it reads from line number 4 from the bottom all the way down to the last line.

```
File.open(FILE) do |f|
  f.readlines[-4..-1]
end
```

Comment: Thanks @bekicot. How would it be on the view?

Comment: It is a bad practice to do it in the view. You should do it via controller and send the result to the view. Unless i have a very good reason, i would avoid to do it in the view.